# awk add(append/copy) missing colums with values based on previously matched 1st and 2nd column

Tags: awk, match, multiple-columns, addition

input file sample format: filea

```
    dataev 258 aaa val1 val3 val4 trim val 7999
    dataev 259 bbb 1 35 aa ff ggg dataev 259 bbb val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
    dataev 26 ccc 2 10 aa ff ggg dataev 26 ccc val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
    dataev 26 ddd val1 val3 val4 trim val 7999
    dataev 262 qqqq 1 38 aa ff ggg dataev 262 qqqq val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
    dataev 263 aaa 1 39 bb ff ggg dataev 263 aaa val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
    dataev 264 ppp val1 val3 val4 trim x64 7999
    dataev 264 888 1 40 cc ff ggg dataev 264 888 val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
    dataev 265 ooo 1 41 bb ff ggg dataev 265 ooo val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
```

based on input file , should be added missing columns (copied) based on match of column $1 and $2 and appended to those where is missing columns and values
from their "matched longer line/row"

output:

```
dataev 258 aaa val1 val3 val4 trim val 7999
dataev 259 bbb 1 35 aa ff ggg dataev 259 bbb val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
dataev 26 ccc 2 10 aa ff ggg dataev 26 ccc val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
dataev 26 ddd 2 10 aa ff ggg dataev 26 ddd val1 val3 val4 trim val 7999
dataev 262 qqqq 1 38 aa ff ggg dataev 262 qqqq val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
dataev 263 aaa 1 39 bb ff ggg dataev 263 aaa val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
dataev 264 ppp 1 40 cc ff ggg dataev 264 ppp val1 val3 val4 trim x64 7999
dataev 264 888 1 40 cc ff ggg dataev 264 888 val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
dataev 265 ooo 1 41 bb ff ggg dataev 265 ooo val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
```

...

its a file with 5k rows and for simplicity if that will help could be concatenated to following output format as well

output:

```
dataev 258 aaa val1 val3 val4 trim val 7999
dataev 259 bbb 1 35 aa ff ggg dataev 259 val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
dataev 26 ccc 2 10 aa ff ggg dataev 26 val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
dataev 26 ddd 2 10 aa ff ggg dataev 26 val1 val3 val4 trim val 7999
dataev 262 qqqq 1 38 aa ff ggg dataev 262 val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
dataev 263 aaa 1 39 bb ff ggg dataev 263 val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
dataev 264 ppp 1 40 cc ff ggg dataev 264 val1 val3 val4 trim x64 7999
dataev 264 888 1 40 cc ff ggg dataev 264 val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999
dataev 265 ooo 1 41 bb ff ggg dataev 265 val1 val3 val4 set val 7999
```

Comment: Not clear, could you please mention what is the logic behind the values filling more clearly?

Comment: val1 val2 val3 means some random dummy values without any purpose in respected field/column, and logic is to fill the gap from "parent" row in order to have "more normalized" format

Comment: Sorry but you have to be clear more what is the logic of filling values?

Comment: logic is to fill the gap from "parent" row in order to have "more normalized/aligned" format based on column 1,and 2 match

Comment: Parent row? But I could see 2nd last row `dataev 264 888 1 40 cc ff ggg dataev 264 888 val1 val3 val4 set (val/x86) 7999` is having values by which other above rows are getting filled? My question is whichever values should be filled from where to where with condition please?

Comment: yes position could be up or down thats why is "last" not sure how to fix input format to have it in direction from "TOP" to "DOWN", input file format is like i have it

Comment: then using word parent is not good here, it may confuse people. Also from where to where values should be added is NOT answered by you yet. Add in your post your efforts too which you have put to solve this problem.

Comment: word "parent" removed and used instead of it " values from their "matched longer line/row"

Comment: Does the input **really** need to be about 20 rows of 20 columns? Couldn't you demonstrate the problem with, say, 5x5? If you can create a [mcve] it'll be much clearer and you might get more people willing to read it.

Comment: @EdMorton Hi, its shortened a bit , it was longer due many multiple complains in multiple articles, thats are posted only specific data, except of getting whole picture of the problem, it looks i am getting closer to my problem to be solved, so will keep you posted about results, thank you

Comment: Right, posting so little data that it doesn't demonstrate your problem isn't adequate, and posting so much data that it obscures your problem (can't see the forest for the trees) also isn't adequate. You have to put some effort into coming up with a [mcve] to stand the best chance of getting help. I still feel like you could demonstrate your requirements with about 3 to 6 fields per line instead of about 20 fields per line. I get the feeling what you need to do would be absolutely trivial if you could just show us a [mcve] so we don't have to read a ton of data to spot the in->out mappings.

Comment: And you're going to have to provide **SOME** kind of clue about how to identify which fields are "missing" from a given line and how to identify which fields to copy from the previous line, assuming that is what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for your inputs